# Поиск значения даты в строке VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

есть функция на VBA, которая на вход получает номер строки, на основании которого записывает в переменную из нужного столбца дату. Функция должна найти в определенной строке (в таблице это временная шкала) эту дату и сохранить номер столбца результата. Сейчас это выглядит примерно так:

```
Function findTask1(row)
    Dim d As Date
    d = Cells(row, 16)
    MsgBox d
    With Worksheets(1).Rows(7)
        Set c = Cells.Find(d, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            findTask1 = c.column
            MsgBox "НАШЕЛ В :" + CStr(c.column)
        Else
            MsgBox "НЕ НАШЕЛ"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Проблема в том, что находит эту же самую ячейку, которая грубо говоря задается условием. Пробовал разные варианты поиска, нужного результата не получил( В "заданной" ячейке дата в формате `ДД.ММ.ГГГГ`, в искомой `МММ ДД ГГ`. Заранее всем спасибо)

Comment: Ну так искать надо не на всём листе, а только в нужном диапазоне... Замените `Cells.Find` на какой-нить `Range("F10:X20").Find(...)`. Или, если блок `With` там не просто так, и нужно искать именно в указанной строке, то просто `.Find(...)`.

Comment: Блок With насколько я понимаю как раз и указывает на диапазон, пробовал его менять на аналогичный, указанный вами. Да, искать нужно именно в указанной строке. Просто во остальном коде данный метод работает, но там не даты. А как правильно, если без этого оформить синтаксис .Find?

Comment: Вы бы сделали модель - импортируемый текст со значениями, указания по форматам, код для модуля,- чтобы можно было легко воспроизвести файл... а так на пальцах как-то сложновато.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор `With`  указывает на родителя, а между `With-End With` указываются подчиненные объекты. Но не все, что внутри, относится к родителю.

Пример.

Запишем данные диапазона в массив. Ссылку на диапазон листа пишем обычно так - *родитель(точка)подчиненный*:

```
aData = Worksheets("Лист").Range("A1:C5").Value
```

Объявим объект с помощью `With`:

```
With Worksheets("Лист")
      aData = .Range("A1:C5").Value
      aData2 = Range("D1:E5").Value
End With
```

Здесь диапазон *A1:C5* относится к листу "Лист", а диапазон *D1:E5* - к активному листу.

Теперь, надеюсть, ошибка понятна.

---

Еще один момент, который иногда ставит подножки (вернее, авторы кода сами себе посечку делают).

```
Cells(row, 16)
```

Это может быть и диапазон, и значение. Хорошо, что объявленная переменная `d` которой передается объект, имеет тип `Date`, но все же рекомендую не экономить на символах и, когда нужно получить значение ячейки, явно это прописывать:

```
Cells(row, 16).Value
```

Не забывать о родителе (показана ячейка активного листа).

Не забывать объявлять переменные (в коде из вопроса не объявлена `c`)

Comment: `Не забывать объявлять переменные (в коде из вопроса не объявлена c)` ну так может есть смысл рассказать про `Option Explicit`?

Comment: Да и так много понаписано :)